# Spring Boot WebClient Superclass Deserialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, webclient, spring-webclient

I have a WebClient that gets from an API a response in which one of its fields is the superclass of many other subclasses. For example, lets say that I have a class

```
public class Animal {
  protected String sound;

  public Animal() {
  }

  public String getSound() {
    return sound;
  }

  public void setSound(String sound) {
    this.sound = sound;
  }
}
```

and a couple of subclasses (please, this is just an example)

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
  private String catHouseNumber;

  public Cat() {
    this.sound = "miau";
  }

  public String getCatHouseNumber() {
    return catHouseNumber;
  }

  public void setCatHouseNumber(String catHouseNumber) {
    this.catHouseNumber = catHouseNumber;
  }
}
```

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

  private String dogDesc;

  public Dog() {
    this.sound = "guau";
  }

  public String getDogDesc() {
    return dogDesc;
  }

  public void setDogDesc(String dogDesc) {
    this.dogDesc = dogDesc;
  }
}
```

Then, the response class looks like this

```
public class AnimalData {
  private int id;
  private int age;
  private int name;
  private Animal animalSpec;

  public AnimalData() {
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public int getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(int name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Animal getAnimalSpec() {
    return animalSpec;
  }

  public void setAnimalSpec(Animal animalSpec) {
    this.animalSpec = animalSpec;
  }
}
```

When I make the call with webclient.get()... I need to deserialize 'animalSpec', in AnimalData class, to one of Dog or Cat

I tried to customize an ObjectMapper but it didn't work

Comment: What means "it didn't work"? What is the expected result?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the polymorphic deserialization of *animalSpec* in your *AnimalData* class, you'll need to provide Jackson with additional information about the type of the subclass being used. This can be achieved using annotations or a custom deserializer.

1. Add Jackson Annotations: In your *Animal* class, add a ***@JsonTypeInfo*** annotation with ***use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME*** and ***include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY***. This will include a type identifier in the JSON for deserialization. (In this example, I'm assuming that the type identifier in the JSON is named "type". You can adjust the property attribute accordingly if it's named differently in your actual JSON.)

   ```
   public class Animal {
   // ... existing code ...

   @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
   protected String sound;

   // ... existing code ...}
   ```
2. Add Subtype Annotations: In each of your subclass (*Cat* and *Dog*), add a ***@JsonTypeName*** annotation with a unique name.

   ```
   @JsonTypeName("dog") 
   public class Dog extends Animal{
   // ... existing code ...}
   ```
3. Deserialize with ObjectMapper: When you receive the JSON response and need to deserialize it, use an ***ObjectMapper*** with ***@JsonTypeInfo*** support:

   ```
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
   AnimalData animalData = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, AnimalData.class);
   ```

The ***enableDefaultTyping*** method is used to configure the ***ObjectMapper*** to include type information in the serialized JSON.